# Backup apps on Linux after a certain date

Tags: linux, backup

Is there a way to back up applications installed after a certain point in time?

Example: I would like to back up all the applications that have been installed within the last month. Is this possible? It's okay if it's not an entire application and just an upgrade too that counted as an installation.

Comment: Do you want to backup application data, application files? Are these applications installed from distribution repository (using deb or rpm) or are they installed form source packages (tar.gz, tgz)?

Comment: @Grzegorz Most were installed from the distribution repositories. As for the source packages, I can install them manually later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command

```
find /start/directory -type f -atime +n -print
```

will find and write to stdout all files accessed more than *`n`* days ago. If you wish to find those that were *modified* more than *`n`* days ago, use `mtime` instead of `atime`.

You can now modify this command to provide a backup, like

```
find /start/directory -type f -atime +n -exec cp {} /backup/dir \;
```

or simply you can output all file names to a file

```
find /start/dir -type f -atime +n -print > file_list.txt
```

and then act on this list as you see fit.

Comment: But the question is about applications installed ***after*** a certain time (date), so you would need to use, for example, `-mtime -30`, to find all files whose modification date/time is less than 30 days in the past.

Comment: @Scott Thank you for your correction, Scott, I was being the usual absent-minded myself.